# Google Cloud API Speech is changed?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, google-cloud-endpoints

From several weeks I'm using the python script provided from python-docs-samples:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/api/speech_streaming.py

Until few days ago all worked fine.
Today every time I start the script I immediately receive a response with endpoint = 0 (unspecified) and endpoint = 3 (end of audio) as described here:

https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v1beta1#google.cloud.speech.v1beta1.StreamingRecognizeResponse.EndpointerType

Anyone is aware if they changed something? The API are still in Beta, so I'm expecting some undocumented changes...

Comment: Found. I had to increase the deadline timout. I have never seen this message until now!

Comment: glad you found an answer. You should write a full answer so that other people with the same problem can fix it.